# Javascript to detect 32-bit vs 64-bit firefox on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox

On a mac, is there a javascript object to test if firefox is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

I have a page which uses a plugin which is supported on a mac only under FireFox and only in 32-bit mode. Using the user agent, it's easy enough to detect the browser, but I can't find a way to detect if the browser is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: Try to detect it using `navigator` object.

Comment: Probably the closest you can come with JS is checking either the window.navigator.cpuClass or the window.navigator.platform.

Comment: The plugin is Sibelius-Scorch. The cpuClass seems to report on the OS, not the broswer. The navigator platform seems to report MacIntel.

Comment: @j08691 On my machine, `navigator.platform` returns `"Win32"` even though I have 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - I didn't say it was perfect ;)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - You are probably running 32-bit Firefox, as all other Windows users.